# Trying an If Statement with the Connection Open

Tags: c#, sql, if-statement

I am trying to make an if statement in case I could not open a connection to SQL Server, to display a label, and alternatively to display another form. The code is as follows:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx.ac.uk;Initial Catalog=XXXX;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxxx");

    try
    {
       // string sql = "SELECT * FROM datatable";
        SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM datatable", conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
                if (mycommand != null)
                label1.Visible = true;
                label1.Text = "Failed to Access Database! Please log into VPN Using The Link Below.";
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn != null)

            this.Hide();
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        form.Show();


    }

    }

}

}
```

Whenever I run the file offline, I get a timeout issue and I am unable to use the app as I get an exception. I want an if statement to check if there is a connection then to go to the form and if there is not, then show the label.

Regards, any help appreciated.

Comment: You should probably remove your unsername and password for your database connection string.

Answer (score 1):

I think your method is trying to do a bit too much. You shouldn't have to query a table. Simply opening the connection should be enough.

```
var canAccessDB = false;

try
{
    conn.Open();
    canAccessDB = true; // Will only get here if Open() is successful
}
catch
{
    // nothing needed here
}
finally
{
    if (conn != null)
        conn.Dispose(); // Safely clean up conn
}

if (!canAccessDB)
{
    label1.Visible = true;
    label1.Text = "Failed to Access Database! Please log into VPN Using The Link Below.";
}
else
{
    this.Hide();
}

Form1 form = new Form1();
form.Show();
```

Comment: You still need a `catch` for the `conn.Open()` `try` block which swallows the exception

Comment: thank you for that, but i am still getting the same exception on the conn.open() part

Comment: @user2040978 `Open` should throw an exception if the db is not available. But the `catch` block hides that from the user.

Answer (score 0):

A finally block will run every time.  You need a catch block with code to execute in case there is a problem with what is in the try block.

Comment: do you mean just swapping the finally with the catch?

Comment: I see two finallys and no catches in your post.  Hard to make a swap.

Answer (score 0):

You could catch the SqlException if the connection fails and display the message to the user

```
using (SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM datatable", conn))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        label1.Visible = true;
        label1.Text = string.Format("Failed to Access Database! Please log into VPN Using The Link Below.\r\n\r\nError: {0}", ex.Message);
        return;
    }

    if (conn != null)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        form.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: and where would i put the form to open in case the connection is established

Comment: You can add under the catch and in th cattch you can return out.